# cannot import widget.CalendarView in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-query

Please help, I'm working on CalendarView but my project cannot import this widget in source code(via intelisense or type manually). What would I need to do? My project is base on android 2.2 and above.

Comment: explain further on cannot import, does it give you an error, or do nothing?

Comment: I have found out! It's because my android project was base on android 2.2 it should be base on android 3.0 above ( >= API 11 )in order to use calenderView and import android.widget.calendarView

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a higher Api for that like Android 3.0 plus. Android 2.2 doesn't support calendar view unless you use external libraries.